# How do I add a Header for Rows in a 2D Array?

Tags: c++

I Need to output an 2D Array that has a label header for the colums and the rows.
the columns is easy i just ouput a string above the table but i cannot figure out how to add the word ROW in vertical letters at the begining of the table.
it has to look like this.

```
         C o l u m n s

     |   1   2   3   4   5   6

----------------------------------

   1 |   2   3   4   5   6   7

R  2 |   3   4   5   6   7   8

O  3 |   4   5   6   7   8   9

W  4 |   5   6   7   8   9  10

S  5 |   6   7   8   9  10  11

   6 |   7   8   9  10  11  12
```

i cannot figure out how to get the rows label

Comment: What code do you have? How are you storing the array, how are you printing it? Where would the labels come from, hardcoded?

Comment: Providing a [mcve] is going to be helpful to readers who wants to help you.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, you could print the row labels before you start printing the martix columns.  You could also figure out, mathematically, the center row for "ROWS", then figure  out when to start  the "ROWS" word.  Search the internet for "centering formula" or "equation for centering".